# Google Apps Script: Retrieve Date from Spreadsheet and write to Contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

Using Google Apps script, I'm trying to take a date written in a spreadsheet and add it as a date field to a Contact. Specifically, I cannot seem to convert the month of the javascript date read from the spreadsheet into a [month enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/month) that the [contact.addDate method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#addDate(Object,Month,Integer,Integer)) can use.

```
var months = ContactsApp.Month.values;
var birthdate = new Date( spreadsheet_date );
var month = months[ birthdate.getMonth() ];
contact.addDate(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY, 
     month, birthdate.getDate(), birthdate.getFullYear() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to approach, as I see a switch is the easiest, there's no one-liner though, as there's no month name built into Javascript:

```
var month = birthdate.getMonth();
switch(month){
   case 0:
      month = ContactsApp.Month.JANUARY;
      break;
   case 1:
      month = ContactsApp.Month.FEBRUARY;
      break;
   [...]
   case 11:
      month = ContactsApp.Month.DECEMBER
      break;
}
```

Comment: Yikes, a switch statement. Definitely makes sense though I was hoping for something a little more concise. Thanks. In an ideal world there should be a better way...

Comment: @RKM Yeah, other options are a series of if's (duh!), or getting the name of the name, converting to uppercase and reference the object: `var calendarMonth = ContactsApp.Month[ convertNumberToMonth( birthdate.getMonth() ).toUpperCase(). ]`, but  `convertNumberToMonth()` should be also a Switch.

Answer (score 1):

another pattern...

```js
var arr = [
    CalendarApp.Month.JANUARY,
    CalendarApp.Month.FEBRUARY,
    CalendarApp.Month.MARCH,
    ...
];
var month = arr[birthdate.getMonth()];
```

Answer (score 0):

See how I'm doing it in this post of a different question I have, here

[Google Contact "Birthday" field not showing when set from Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989513/google-contact-birthday-field-not-showing-when-set-from-apps-script).

You need a mapping from the enum to the month name.  This will avoid the long switch statement.  This solution was initially provided to me by @tehhowch.

Answer (score 0):

```
var month = months[ birthdate.getMonth() ];
var monthAsInt={JANUARY:1,FEBRUARY:2,MARCH:3,APRIL:4,MAY:5,JUNE:6,JULY:7
  ,AUGUST:8,SEPTEMBER:9,OCTOBER:10,NOVEMBER:11,DECEMBER:12}[month];
```

as a function;

```
function monthToInt(month) {
  return {JANUARY:1,FEBRUARY:2,MARCH:3,APRIL:4,MAY:5,JUNE:6,JULY:7
      ,AUGUST:8,SEPTEMBER:9,OCTOBER:10,NOVEMBER:11,DECEMBER:12}[month];
}
```