# Google Contact "Birthday" field not showing when set from Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I am having a problem in Apps Script setting the Birthday field in a Google Contact.  I have a Form with a "User's Date of Birth" field and my code is called upon FormSubmit from the receiving spreadsheet.  It looks like this:

```
  // h/t @tehhowch for this mapping solution
  var months = ContactsApp.Month;
  var monthToEnum = {
    1: months.JANUARY,
    2: months.FEBRUARY,
    3: months.MARCH,
    ...,
    12: months.DECEMBER
  };

  // get the date from the event parameter e
  var d = new Date(e.namedValues["User's Date of Birth"]);
  var birthdayMonth = d.getMonth()+1;  // getMonth() returns offset 0
  var birthdayDay   = d.getDate();
  var birthdayYear  = d.getFullYear();
  var monthEnum     = monthToEnum[birthdayMonth];

  Logger.log("Birthday: " + birthdayMonth + "/" + birthdayDay 
           + "/" + birthdayYear + " and " + monthEnum);

  contact.addDate(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY, monthEnum, 
                  birthdayDay, birthdayYear);

  Logger.log("formSubmittedSheetNewPatient: contact Birthday = "
           + contact.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0].getMonth());
```

The first log correctly shows "`Birthday: 2/21/1912 and FEBRUARY`" and the second is "`contact Birthday = FEBRUARY`" so the code works.  Then I add the new contact to an existing group.  But when I look at the new contact in Google Contacts the default built-in Birthday field is empty and there is no other Birthday field.  All the other fields I'm setting in the new contact are there.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or is there a bug in the Contact Birthday field code?

Comment: In my environment, I cannot replicate your situation. So can you provide the script for replicating it? It will help users think of about the solution of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I enclosed my code.  It's straightforward and the contact object clearly has the Birthday field because I can retrieve it right after in the logging statement.  I go to my contacts and I have the new contact I just created and all the other fields, but the Birthday field, which seems to be a standard field, is empty.  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: for some time, the birthday field no longer displays the date but when I ask with script "Contacts[0].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY);" the information is still there. It seems that it's a problem of this field
for information, I entered the birthday directly in the Google Contact, I did not use the script.

Comment: @Christian - very interesting.  I'm going to have to dig into whether this is a known but with Contacts.  Thanks for your comment here.

Comment: @Christian - I just tried it an you are right!  Gotta be a Contacts bug.